# Странность при передаче DataContext

Tags: c#, wpf

Это вопрос не "как сделать", а хочется понять "почему так происходит".

Есть окно, в нем DataGrid, в DataGrid есть DataGridTemplateColumn, в котором DataTemplate c UserControl

Внутри целевого UserControl нужен как DataContext пункта, так и родительский DataContext окна для биндинга к командам.

Пробуем вариант с явной передачей, чтобы не париться с AncestorLevel

Чтобы убрать у UserControl зависимость от уровня вложенности мы делаем ему DependencyProperty

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty MainContextProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "MainContext", typeof(object), typeof(CellView), new PropertyMetadata(default(object)));

public object MainContext
{
    get { return (object) GetValue(MainContextProperty); }
    set { SetValue(MainContextProperty, value); }
}
```

Передаем родительский контекст.:

```
 <CellView MainContext="{Binding DataContext, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=UserControl, Mode=OneTime}}" />
```

Контекст внутри UserControl, биндимся на команду:

```
Command="{Binding MainContext.MyCommand, 
        RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl,
        Mode=FindAncestor,
        AncestorLevel=1},
        Mode=OneTime}"
```

И оно не работает. Работает если поставить OneWay. А если сделать AncestorLevel=2, то он доберется до родительского контекста и будет работать и с OneTime

Что происходит с DataContext при такой передаче? И почему OneWay все же работает?

Comment: А чему равен MainContext в UserControl фактически?

Comment: @VladD Повесил на UC Loaded и в нем достал MainContext. И  в студии смотрел и GetType делал. Он равен вьюмодели, которая есть основной DataContext, то есть то, что и ожидается.

Comment: @VladD Может быть такое - контрол инициализируется в своем конструкторе и в тот момент бежит к свойству MainContext, а оно null на тот момент, а уж потом оно только присваивается? Я не знаю когда именно устанавливаются свойства заданные в xaml

Comment: Ага, именно про это сейчас вот пишу ответ как раз.

Comment: Хм, а почему AncestorLevel=2 работает вообще? У вас два вложенных UserControl'а?

Comment: В оригинале таблица в юзерконтроле вложенном в окно. У них одинаковый DataContext. В общем если добраться до оригинального DataContext, то работает.

Answer (score 2):

Думаю, причина в том моменте, когда именно происходит onetime-привязка. Она происходит в момент `InitializeComponent`, когда читается и интерпретируется XAML.

В этот момент, судя по всему, привязка `MainContext` ещё не выполнена, так как внешний `UserControl` ещё не вставлен в визуальное дерево. Так что `Binding` привязывается к значению `null`.

Когда указан `AncestorLevel=2`, `Binding` видит, что при поиске упирается в корень (пока внешний `UserControl` конструируется, это сам `UserControl`). Разрешение привязки откладывается (это многофазный процесс, да), и теперь когда элемент таки вставлен в дерево, нужный Ancestor находится, а у него в тот момент правильное значение `MainContext`.

В случае `OneWay` вместо `OneTime` всё ещё проще: вначале `MainContext` не установлен, но когда все присваивания «улягутся», он поменяется, и это изменение будет «подхвачено» привязкой, ведь она теперь больше не onetime.

Comment: из этого вывод - я должен или юзать аттачед свойство DataContext с наследованием или же создать такое же свойство MainContext у родителя,  а у контрола выставить у этого свойства флаг inherit его и тогда он будет установлен? Или вообще не нужно у контрола тогда свойство такое делать? Я так понял аттачед свойство автоматом наследуется неявно на все вложенное, но обычные свойства не обсуждали.

Comment: @vitidev: Флаг inherit у самого attached-свойства. Я бы создал его с флагом inherit, и привязал на самом верхнем уровне `<Window MainContext="{Binding}" ... />`, а внутри ссылался: `Command="{Binding MainContext.MyCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Mode=OneWay}"`.

Comment: @vitidev: Если, конечно, команда не в контекстном меню, там нужно «подшивать» визуальное дерево.

Comment: для контекстного меню я делаю DataContext как ресурс таким простым методом http://www.thomaslevesque.com/2011/03/21/wpf-how-to-bind-to-data-when-the-datacontext-is-not-inherited/ . Подшивание более громоздко.

Comment: @vitidev: Ну да, но это не позволит разбить код на несколько файлов.

Comment: ну почему же. это ж просто захват унаследованного контекста внутри самого контрола чтобы даже AncestorLevel=1 не писать. А в контрол оно наследованием попадет. В теории. Надо все это попробовать.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42971/discussion-between-vitidev-and-vladd).

Comment: вы призываетесь в чат

Comment: и снова призываетесь в чат.